# Config value being ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I have this in my global.asax.cs file to determine whether or not mock communication services are used.

```
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        bool enableMock = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("EnableMock"));
        if (enableMock)
        {
            Container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>()
                .Install(Configuration.FromXmlFile("WindsorMock.config"));
        }
        else
        {
            Container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>()
                .Install(Configuration.FromXmlFile("Windsor.config"));
        }
```

In my web.config file I have set the EnableMock value to false

```
<add key="communicationServiceUrl" value="http://localhost:49421/CommunicationService.svc"/>
<add key="EnableMock" value="false"/>
```

The problem is it is still using the mock services with the value set to false, anybody know why this might be happening. Also, why when I put a break point in the Application_Start does it never hit?

Comment: Have you stop and restarted the local Web Server?

Comment: @Ardman is on to something, if the application is "started", the `Application_Start` won't fire.

Comment: Though this is not related  to your problem, since you are already using Castle Windsor, why don't you remove the app's dependency on ConfigurationManager?

Comment: @Ardman as per your suggestion restarted the web server but to no avail. I am a web newbie (intern) and this site is pretty well underway, but some additional details that may help: The global.asax is in the CommunicationServices project, one of 10 in the solution. There is a global.asax in the startup project as well and I can break on that if I use System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()

Comment: @HelloWorld that sounds great, but I'm not real familiar with windsor yet, do you know any good resources other than castleproject.org or is that the best start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone that tried to help me on this one but it turned out to be nothing but an oversight on my part. There is an EnableMock value in the communicationservices config file that was still set true that I hadn't noticed before. I hadn't realized there were two config files. I guess I still have a lot to learn about this project.

Answer (score 2):

> Also, why when I put a break point in the `Application_Start` does it never hit?

It's never being hit because `Application_Start` is only fired when the Application "Starts". This means that if you want that method to fire, you have to restart the application in IIS.

Another option would be to move that specific method to the `Application_BeginRequest` method in order to ensure your parsing is correct. That will fire the lookup on every page request. Once you know it's working, then you can move the lookup to the `Application_Start`